# MPMoviePlayerController don't exit full screen mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayer

(ipad 1, iOs 4.3)

I have encountered this bug on ipad: when i add a MPMoviePlayerController to my view and put it on full screen mode all movie player controller don't work (i can see but if i touch it don't work), and i can't exit full screen mode

my code:

```
            //Player video
            self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                           initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.attachment.path]];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
             addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
             object:player];

            [self.player setFullscreen:NO];
            [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
            [self.player play];
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the MPMoviePlayerController where once you're in fullscreen mode and you hold down the fast forward button, letting it go all the way to the end of the video. Thereafter the you just get a black screen and it's stuck.  In other words it does not respond to any taps gestures and you can not get out of this situation.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?